# Are there any editline configuration files available to make it act more like readline?

Tags: configuration, readline

With editline replacing readline in a few software packages I use, the annoyance is growing at editline's behaviors and shortcomings. Is there someone maintaining a configuration file to at least make editline as close in behavior as possible to readline?